# how to get recently uploaded document in document library in C#

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I want to get the recently/ currently uploaded/uploading document from document library of sharepoint site in C#? how can i get it . please help . i want to make checked out the recently uploading document in my work flow with sharepoint. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [CAML Query](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) that queries the Document Library for recent items based on the creation date.
Iterate the resulting items collection and check them out using the [CheckOut() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkout.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what it is exactly that you want to do, but checking out an item as soon as it is added to a document library is very simple to do with a SharePoint Designer workflow.